Is there a way to create a colored text box for StringProperty in addon UI, like the overwrite warning in Blender save-as window?
To store a user setting, I managed to access a StringProperty in my addon popup window like this:

But i want to add an overwrite warning as same as the blender file save window:

Is there a way to do this?
I have been searched the API for some hours, and found that blender has a "check_existing" BoolProperty in "bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile()" to paint the box red. But no more sentenses were found about changing text box color in blender's python scripts.
More than approciate for telling me the way to do that! :)

use layout.alert = True
learn more https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.alert

It works! Additionally, for others who would have watched this question, "row.alert = True" should before the sentenses like "row.prop(self, 'some_str')" or it wont works.
